# Why is a covered query sometimes slower in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I was under the impression that covered queries were always faster than scanning the collection itself. So why is this covered query slower?

**Covered query:**

```
> db.group_panel_responses.find({}, {_id: 0, _panel_id: 1, _group_id: 1, response_count: 1}).hint({_panel_id: 1, _group_id: 1, response_count: -1}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _panel_id_1__group_id_1_response_count_-1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 20000,
    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 20000,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 20000,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : true,
    "nYields" : 156,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 44,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "_panel_id" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ],
        "_group_id" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ],
        "response_count" : [
            [
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "DAAVID.local:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

**Same query but without hinting at the index, so not a covered query:**

```
> db.group_panel_responses.find({}, {_id: 0, _panel_id: 1, _group_id: 1, response_count: 1}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 20000,
    "nscannedObjects" : 20000,
    "nscanned" : 20000,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 20000,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 20000,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 156,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 40,
    "server" : "DAAVID.local:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Comment: Not the best example as both need to scan all items and all items matched. But the short case is one of those needed to load items from the index. So essentially a few more steps in internal code than the optimized form that gave up and decided it was more efficient just to scan. Real world examples will vary in that result.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks, makes a lot of sense. Essentially, if MongoDB needs to scan the entire document, then adding the extra step of using the index slows it down. If MongoDB is using an index and **doesn't** need to scan the entire document, adding the extra step of going back to the collection for each document found in the index slows it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that a query that is covered by an index is generally faster than a regular query because you can retrieve the fields for each document in one step, as opposed to two in a regular query, where you hit the index to find the location of the document and then hit the collection itself to retrieve the fields.

To over simplify a bit, in a normal case where my selection criteria would retrieve 20000 documents, a normal query would have 40000 accesses (20000 for the index and 20000 for the collection) while a covered query would only have 20000 accesses.

In your test case, however, you have no selection criteria. So both queries, covered and uncovered, will do a full collection scan. In this case you lose almost all of the performance boost of a covered query with selection criteria.

If you really want to test the value of a covered query I'd use a much larger document collection and a much more selective query. If the test you are using is representative of your actual production usage I would not expect any performance boost at all.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I somehow thought scanning the index would be faster because the documents would be represented in a more compact format.